# Running Oracle Package: ORA-06550 || ORA-06502

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

When I try to run a package on our oracle database from Oracle's .net provider, or the Microsoft oracle provider, it gives me the following error:

```
{"ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00221: 'BEGIN_TRANSACTION' is not a procedure or is undefined\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored"}
```

Here is my C# code:

```
OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

cmd.Connection = cn;
cmd.CommandText = "DOTNET.SYSTEM_CRUD.BEGIN_TRANSACTION";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


cmd.Parameters.Add("p_user_id", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = 4720;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_commt", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "TEST";
//cmd.Parameters.Add("return_value", OracleDbType.Decimal).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here is my package definition:

```
Function Begin_Transaction ( p_user_id  IN NUMBER,
                             p_commt    IN  VARCHAR2
                            )
  RETURN Number;
```

When I uncomment the third parameter that I've added,  I get a different error:

```
{"ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error\nORA-06512: at line 1"}
```

Comment: `Stored Procedure != Function` ?

Comment: add `cmd.BindByName = true;`

Comment: The other two options that it gives me for command type are "TableDirect" and "Text."

Comment: Where are you define `Begin_Transaction` function? Is it package or not? Common procedure name is "PACKAGE.FUNCTION" but in your case this is something else.

Comment: It's in a package called "SYSTEM_CRUD" owned by the "DOTNET" user

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
{

    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = "DOTNET.SYSTEM_CRUD.BEGIN_TRANSACTION";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.BindByName = true;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_user_id", OracleDbType.Decimal, 4720, ParameterDirection.Input));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_commt", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "TEST", ParameterDirection.Input));

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment:

Don't forgive wrap disposable objects in `using` construction.

Comment: It is still telling me "'BEGIN_TRANSACTION' is not a procedure or is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

I removed the username from the package definition, and also uncommented my add parameter for the return value.

```
using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
                {

                    cmd.Connection = cn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SYSTEM_CRUD.BEGIN_TRANSACTION";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.BindByName = true;


                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_user_id", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = 4720;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_commt", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "TEST";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("return_value", OracleDbType.Decimal).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "SYSTEM_CRUD.BEGIN_TRANSACTION";
cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.Parameters.Add("return_value", OracleDbType.Decimal).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

Were the lines that had to be changed for me. I tried it without all of these and it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that `Begin_Transaction` function compiled successful?

Comment: Yes, the code posted above works! Thanks for your help! I wouldn't have figured out to put cmd.BindByName = true;